# How to theme the Event content type node creation form in drupal 6?

Tags: theming, forms, 6

I have installed Event module which gave me an "Event" content type.

I want to theme the node edit/creation form for the Event content type that automatically comes once the Event module is enabled.

I have tried defining the custom tpl to handle but it's not working. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on what changes you want to make, but the standard way of altering forms in D6 (and D7) is invoking hook_form_alter() in a custom module. Do a switch on the form_id, and enter your edits, something like this:

```
YOUR_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // print $form_id; exit;
  switch($form_id){
    case 'event_node_form':
      // change the form. The following will alter the text on the submit button:
      $form['submit']['#value'] = 'Go!';
      break;
  }
  return $form;
}
```

If you don't know what the form_id is of the form you want to edit, just uncomment the `print $form_id` line and visit the form in your browser. You can refer to the [D6 form api guide](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/6) to find what form elements go with which properties. Hope that helps!

Comment: Hey thanks, there was some issue with my template definition and template handling code in template.php . After a few fixes it worked. Anyways thanks for your answer too @olyN